# Remove a specifc repeated word using python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a ***`string`*** like :

```
'hi', 'what', 'are', 'are', 'what', 'hi'
```

I want to remove a specific repeated word. For example:

```
'hi', 'what', 'are', 'are', 'what'
```

Here, I am just removing the repeated word of `hi`, and keeping rest of the repeated words.

How to do this using `regex`?

Comment: You don't need regex for that (Unless it is mandatory)

Comment: Do you need to preserve the order?

Comment: Can you give me any solution? and it is not mandatory to use regex from my side.

Comment: @KotaMori yes, i have to maintain the order

Comment: @Selcuk I believe this question is completely different then you had closed(duplicated) for!

Comment: @ShamimMahbub I believe `"'hi', 'what', 'are', 'are', 'what', 'hi'"`  is what you want to write ?

Comment: @Xitiz No, please follow the question.

Comment: @ShamimMahbub Copy/Paste what you are tried to do. Don't edit anything just copy/paste from your IDE exactly!

Comment: 'mode', 'name', 'phase', 'round', 'team_ct', 'score', 'name', 'mode'.... this is the actual string on which I am working on.. it is an output from a variable, and the type of the variable is a string. I just want to keep the 1st 'mode'.

Comment: Sadly your question is closed but I will try to answer here, if any confusion then ask. Formatting will be vary bad but I will comment that will work by just doing copy/paste

Comment: `arrayOfWords ='mode', 'name', 'phase', 'round', 'team_ct', 'score', 'name', 'mode';arrayOfWords=list(arrayOfWords);specificword="mode";[arrayOfWords.remove(specificword) for x in arrayOfWords if arrayOfWords.count(specificword)>1];print(arrayOfWords)`

Comment: OR THIS `arrayOfWords ="'mode', 'name', 'phase', 'round', 'team_ct', 'score', 'name', 'mode'";import ast;arrayOfWords=list(ast.literal_eval(arrayOfWords));specificword="mode";[arrayOfWords.remove(specificword) for x in arrayOfWords if arrayOfWords.count(specificword)>1];print(arrayOfWords)`

Comment: @ShamimMahbub Answered! Check it. :)

Comment: @Xitiz, 1st one is not working, and 2nd one deleting all mode

Comment: which `arrayOfWords` is correct? 1st one or 2nd one?

Comment: @Xitiz 2nd one is correct

Comment: Okay! I am confused not why it is deleting all "mode" it is working perfectly for me. Can you provide expected output for `arrayOfWords ="'mode', 'name', 'phase', 'round', 'team_ct', 'score', 'name', 'mode'"`?

Comment: @Xitiz, I really loved your efforts for my problem. I am getting the expected result. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ShamimMahbub UPVOTE that answer which is working fro you, by upvoting that comment will go to top and may help future people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
import re
s= "['hi', 'what', 'are', 'are', 'what', 'hi']"
# convert string to list. Remove first and last char, remove ' and empty spaces
s=s[1:-1].replace("'",'').replace(' ','').split(',')
remove = 'hi'
# store the index of first occurance so that we can add it after removing all occurance
firstIndex = s.index(remove)
# regex to remove all occurances of a word
regex = re.compile(r'('+remove+')', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
op = regex.sub("", '|'.join(s)).split('|')
# clean up the list by removing empty items
while("" in op) :
    op.remove("")
# re-insert the removed word in the same index as its first occurance
op.insert(firstIndex, remove)
print(str(op))
```

Comment: Actually OP is asking for specific word, right?

Comment: That `s` is in `string` not in `list`!

Comment: @ShreyasPrakash that is good, but it removing all **hi**

Comment: @Xitiz, can you help me with this?

Comment: @ShamimMahbub how about now? Addressed Xitiz comment also

Comment: @ShreyasPrakash, that is what I am asking for... thanks a lot.. but can you explain the code? please.

Comment: @ShamimMahbub I have added comments in the code

Answer (score 1):

Regex is used for text search. You have structured data, so this is unnecessary.

```py
def remove_all_but_first(iterable, removeword='hi'):
    remove = False
    for word in iterable:
        if word == removeword:
            if remove:
                continue
            else:
                remove = True
            yield word
```

Note that this will return an iterator, not a list. Cast the result to list if you need it to remain a list.

Comment: as far as i know, regex also can subtract repeated words.

Comment: @ShamimMahbub you're incorrect. Regex is a shortening of Regular Expressions, which are a way to do pattern matching in a [Regular Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). It does not solve the generalized form of "subtract repeated words." You could certainly craft a regex that will do what you want for some subsets of input, but since lists are not regular languages -- they are structured data -- regex is not the tool for this job.

Comment: I do not have a list, I have a text file, which is string @

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for that, convert the string to list and then you can find the index of the first occurrence of the word and filter it from a slice of the rest of the list

```
lst = "['hi', 'what', 'are', 'are', 'what', 'hi']"
lst = ast.literal_eval(lst)
word = 'hi'

index = lst.index('hi') + 1
lst = lst[:index] + [x for x in lst[index:] if x != word]
print(lst) # ['hi', 'what', 'are', 'are', 'what']
```

Comment: I have a string object, not a list.. can you do this for string?

Comment: @ShamimMahbub are you telling `lst` from this answer is in string for you?

Comment: yes, that is what I am saying.

Comment: @ShamimMahbub you can change it to a list using `lst = ast.literal_eval(lst)`

Comment: @Xitiz AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'literal_eval', i amgetting this error.

Comment: @ShamimMahbub `ast` should be an import, don't define it yourself. `import ast`

Comment: okay, and now i am getting this error: TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple

Comment: @ShamimMahbub You haven't responded my edit! Is that what you want, right?

Comment: @Xitiz, no, now see the question that i have edited